# how to get url from link inside the notification email

Tags: email, url, hyperlink, outlook, webdriver

I am looking to write a script with web driver where I need to wait for the notification email and then need to get the URL from link of that email.

Comment: which language do you prefer to parse an email?

Comment: I am using java for my script

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for recognising a URL (based off RFC 3986)

```
private static final Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(
        "(?:^|[\\W])((ht|f)tp(s?):\\/\\/|www\\.)"
                + "(([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,}?([\\w\\-.~]+\\/?)*"
                + "[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#\\-+()\\[\\]\\*$~@!:/{};']*)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);


//Usage: email content goes as input here..
Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher("foo bar http://example.com baz");

while (matcher.find()) {
    int matchOffsetStart = matcher.start(1);
    int matchOffsetEnd = matcher.end();
    // now you have the offsets of a URL match
}
```

UPDATE: 
If you want to read message header like FROM and so on, I would suggest to use [Mime4J](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html)

```
Message msg = new Message(new FileInputStream("mime.msg"));
```

`msg.getFrom()` would give you from. Similarly you can extract whatever you want.

[Refer for more details here](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/message/Message.html)

Comment: Thank you Sunil for the pattern, before that I need to wait and validate the email first than I will parse the content of that email.

Comment: validate email -  do you mean the right person as sender? I didn't get you completely

Comment: My steps should be - 1. Need to check if the expected email has been send or not, 2. Then I will parse the url and continue with it.

Comment: Thank you Sunil for another addition. I need the notification email event. For example: If any user submit an application from any web site and than the user gets a submission email. I need to check that email fires for that user than I will check header, or pattern of the email or anything else of that email. Hope that make sense.

Comment: that just flew over my head :P 
Anyway as per my understanding, you need a listener for inbox for incoming mail for an user. Right?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Exactly that is :)